# how to get value in 2D or 3D map in SCSS

Tags: sass

I know can get value in 1D map with `map-get()` function but dont know how get value like 'header' in this map:

```
 $mobile-layout: (
   layout-values: (
     header: (
       height: 72px
     ),
     sidebar: (
       width: 100%
     )
   )
);
```

Comment: i found a sample but is not best solution.https://codepen.io/and1lt/pen/oZEyxe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a couple nested loop solutions...

[DEMO](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/58f577c91f53bfefb8a04304cb514c15)

3 loops

```
@each $key, $val in $mobile-layout {
  @each $k, $v in $val {
    @each $l, $t in $v {
      .#{$k} {
        .#{$l}: #{$t};
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2 loops

```
@each $key, $val in $mobile-layout {
  @each $k, $v in $val {
    .#{$k} {
      .#{map-keys($v)}: #{map-values($v)};
    }
  }
}
```